# Подключение Font Awesome в проекте на Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack, fontawesome

Мне нужно добавить в проект на Vue.js шрифтовые значки Font Awesome, часто используемые в связке с Bootstrap.

Но у меня не получается это сделать.

Предыстория:

---

```
nvm install 8.11.3 x64
nvm use 8.11.3
```

---

Установка Vue.js и создание проекта:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
npm vue ui
```

Шаги мастера создания проекта:

1. Менеджер пакетов - NPM

[image: Менеджер пакетов - NPM]

2. Ручной выбор компонентов

[image: Ручной выбор компонентов]

3. Компоненты: Babel, Vuex, SASS, ESLint, Unit Testing (последний на вырост)

[image: Компоненты: Babel, Vuex, SASS, ESLint, Unit Testing]

4. CSS pre-processot: SCSS/SASS; ESLint + standart config; testing - Jest

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем добавил Bootsrap:

```
npm install bootstrap-vue bootstrap --save

# main.js
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

# App.vue
<style lang="scss">
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
</style>
```

Стили Bootstrap 4 взлетели. Нехватает поддержки Font Awesome... но от обилия вариантов у меня глаза разбегаются:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Повторю вопрос:

**Как добавить в проект на Vue.js шрифтовые значки Font Awesome?**

Желательно, плагином Vue, т.к. в теории там ожидается сборка только используемых частей...

---

**PS** Я новичок в Vue.js и если неправильно подключил Bootstrap, прошу поправить..))

Comment: Охренеть, скоро сайты будут через конструктор "программировать". Vue.js никак не связан с Font Awesome, это просто стили. Добавьте их в package.json и импортните в scss

Comment: Зря ругаетесь - удобный инструментарий, особенно для новичка в Vue.js как я)) 
Поясните пожалуйста свой ответ, какой пакет нужно подключить в  package.json и какой у него путь для импорта (добавил в вопрос ещё один скрин - нижний)?

Comment: Да я не ругаюсь, скорее обидно, что когда запускал первый каркас у меня такого не было))) пакет первый, путь аналогично подключению бутстрепа (посмотрите где лежат стили от него в node_modules)

Comment: =O npm install нашё всё :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

Просто ставим пакет *font-awesome 4.7.0* и импортируем стиль.
Использование согласно документации v4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо, за подсказку [@artem-gorlachev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/219254/artem-gorlachev) ))

---

**Вариант 2**

Посложнее:

1. Ставим пакет *@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome 0.1.1*
2. Доставляем нужные SVG значки, например:

   ```
   npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core  
   npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons  
   npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons  
   npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
   ```
3. Объявляем имя user-tag и юзаем новый тег, согласно документации пакета.

Плюс в том, что получаем последнюю версию "шрифта", на сейчас это версия 5.2.0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Итоговый размер проекта у меня получился примерно одинаковый:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тяжеловато однако, но пока не знаю как уменьшить... ))